# Block face with Adobe Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, brushes

i'm new into Adobe Lightroom and don't have any basic skills with it. I want to ask a question that maybe this is very basic to you.

Please take a look on picture below, the object's face is blocked with black color, how to block face with Adobe Lightroom like this? Can i done this with brush/something else?

[image: Source : Instagram]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there a reason you *need* to use Lightroom for this? It would be much simpler in our favourite image editor (Photoshop, GIMP, Paint.NET, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion. I just curious is there any way to do this with Lightroom. Anyway, thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and very easy. Choose Adjustment Brush tool (<kbd>K</kbd> in Wiindows), set Exposure to the lowest level and paint on parts of the image you want to be black. If the "blackness" is transparent, just paint once again over it!

Here is an example:

[image: A bird]

Comment: Many thanks for you! Thanks for _teach_ me the way, and thanks too for the example :D

Comment: "Jonathan Livingston Seagull wished to remain anonymous at the beach."